# How to minify a filtered javascript file using maven?

Tags: javascript, maven, filter, minify

I have a javascript file that is used to track events using Google analytics. I have created different accounts for the staging and production environment. The script to invoke GA code has a place holder for my account Id. The account Ids have been specified in the filter files. Using the webResources element in the maven-war plugin, we are able to successfully replace the property in the final WAR file.

Now, we are also using maven-yuicompressor plugin to minify and aggregate all our javascript files. The problem is that if I attach the execution of minify goal to the package phase, the WAR is created before the Javascript has been minified. If I attach the minify goal to anything earlier, the filter has been not applied till the time of minification producing an invalid file.

So, I am looking for a way to run the minify goal between the WAR plugin copying the filtered JS files and creating the WAR file. Here are the relevant portions of my pom.xml:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <webResources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/webapp/js</directory>
                  <targetPath>js</targetPath>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </webResources>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>compress</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <linebreakpos>-1</linebreakpos>
              <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
              <force>true</force>
              <aggregations>
                <aggregation>
                  <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js/mysite-min.js</output>
                  <inputDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js</inputDir>
                  <includes>
                    <include>jquery-1.4.2.js</include>
                    <include>jquery-ui.min.js</include>
                    <include>ga-invoker.js</include>
                  </includes>
                </aggregation>
              </aggregations>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: May be bind it to `prepare-package` ?

Comment: As I mentioned before, attaching to anything before package phase is not working since the filter has not been applied till then. The war plugin copies the web resources and applies the filter as part of the package phase itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you put the filtered js files in src/main/resources/filtered-js, use the resources plugin instead, which binds to `process-resources`, then point the webresources config of the maven-war-plugin to `target/classes/filtered-js`?

Comment: You have beaten me to posting the answer. I did something similar yesterday. I let the yuicompressor plugin remain attached to the process-resources phase which is the default but configured its output to go to target/js. Then I used maven-war plugin's webResources configuration to filter the contents of this directory and put them into target/<build.finalname>/js. Still have to mark your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 10):

Great question, great anwser by artbristol, which i voted up. It helped me a lot. For future reference i post a complete solution:

- Put your Javascript files into `src/main/resources/js` (or whatever fits your needs)
- Put your CSS files into `src/main/resources/css` (or whatever fits your needs)
- Resources plugin is filtering your javascript resources and copies them to `target/classes/js/`
- Yui is picking up the files at target/classes/js/ and aggregates them to `src/main/webapp`
- You can test your setup with `jetty:run`. Jetty is picking up the compressed and aggregated files in `src/main/webapp`
- war plugin at package phase is picking up your files under `src/main/webapp`
- optional put a SCM ignore file like `.svnignore` or `.cvsignore` file into `src/main/webapp` to exclude `all.js` from your favourite SCM tool.

The excludes section is necessary to avoid compressing anything in src/main/resources and src/main/webapp. yui should just pickup already filtered files for aggregation.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <force>true</force>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>   
                <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
                <aggregations>
                    <aggregation>
                        <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
                        <output>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/js/all.js</output>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/js/file1.js</include>
                            <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/js/file2.js</include>
                    </aggregation>
                    <aggregation>
                        <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
                        <output>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/css/all.css</output>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/css/file1.css</include>
                            <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/css/file2.css</include>
                    </aggregation>
                </aggregations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Why would you want filtering of css files?

i use it to reference my images like this

```
div.header {
  background-image: url(/img/background.${project.version}.png)
}
```

Maven filters my project version into my css files. Any incoming request on our imageserver is filtered **like** this

```
protected void doHttpFilter ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    if (isStaticRequest(uri))
    {
        String uriWithoutVersion = stripVersionString(uri);
        String versionRequested = getVersionString(uri);
        if (version.equals(versionRequested))
        {
            response.setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER_NAME, CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER_VALUE);
            response.setHeader(EXPIRES_HEADER_NAME, EXPIRES_HEADER_VALUE);
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(uriOhneVersionsnummer);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
}
```

this way the browser caches each file forever. but when i upload a new version all file reference have a new version number, so the browser is fetching the image or css again.
this helped us a lot to reduce traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Maven Minify Plugin to compress the javascript and css files. It also merges these files into one single file.This is working fine

I have used maven-timestamp plugin to put a unque suffix to these file as a browser cache solution.This is also working fine

The thing i am stuck with is how to replace all the reference of the js and css with the ones newly created  at the build execution time.

I am looking into maven-replace-plugin for the same. It can remove all instances.It can replace with new values. But I need to keep one instance of the newly merged-minified js and css.

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.keyboardsamurais.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-timestamp-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
     <propertyName>timestamp</propertyName>
     <timestampPattern>ddMMyyyyHHmm</timestampPattern>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>create</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <!-- here the phase you need -->
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/resources/themes</outputDirectory>
       <resources>
        <resource>
         <includes>
          <include>**/*.vm</include>
         </includes>
         <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/themes</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
       </resources>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-minify-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>default-minify</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
       <cssSourceDir>../resources/themes/XXXX/default/template-resources/stylesheet</cssSourceDir>
       <cssSourceIncludes>
        <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
       </cssSourceIncludes>
       <cssFinalFile>style.css</cssFinalFile>
       <jsSourceDir>../resources/themes/XXXX/default/template-resources/js</jsSourceDir>
       <jsSourceIncludes>
        <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
       </jsSourceIncludes>
       <jsSourceFiles>
        <jsSourceFile>/libs/json.js</jsSourceFile>
       </jsSourceFiles>
       <jsFinalFile>script.js</jsFinalFile>
       <suffix>-${timestamp}</suffix>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
       <goal>minify</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>replace</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <includes>
      <include>target/resources/themes/XXXX/default/templates/velocity/**/*.vm</include>
     </includes>
     <replacements>
      <replacement>
       <token><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" href="/storefront/template-resources/stylesheet/]]>([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*.css)<![CDATA[" type="text/css"/>]]>([])</token>      
       <value></value>
      </replacement>
         <replacement>
       <token><![CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" href="/storefront/template-resources/stylesheet/powerreviews]]>([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*.css)<![CDATA[" type="text/css"/>]]></token>      
       <value></value>
      </replacement>

      <replacement>
       <token><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="/storefront/template-resources/js/]]>([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]*.js)<![CDATA["></script>]]></token>
       <value></value>
      </replacement>
      <replacement>
       <token><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="/storefront/template-resources/js/libs/]]>([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]*.js)<![CDATA["></script>]]></token>
       <value></value>
      </replacement>
     </replacements>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>dist</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
       <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
       </descriptors>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Comment: for cache-busting, you may want to use MD5 checksums rather than timestamps. With timestamps, your cache will be invalidated every time you do a build irrespective of whether you change the JS and CSS.